# Barrier function in Dirichlet problem

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider the Dirichlet problem as follows:

$U \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ open and bounded set such that there exists a Barrier function. By Perron's method we know that there exists a unique harmonic function $u \in C(\overline{U}) \cap C^2 (U)$ with $u=f$ on $\partial U$.

That's correct? So my question is: What is this announced "Barrier function" exactly? And why is it necessary for our $U$?

Answer (score 0):

With Perron's method, you construct the solution as an envelope

$$u(x) = \sup\{v(x) \, : \, v \text{ subharmonic and } v\leq f \text{ on } \partial U\}.$$

It is possible that $u\neq f$ on $\partial U$ (for example, a boundary layer may develop). Basically, barrier functions are harmonic functions in neighborhoods of boundary points that bound each $v$ from above and below (via the maximum principle). This ensures that $u$ attains the boundary values $f$ continuously and hence solves the boundary value problem. For more details you should read the relevant sections in Gilbarg-Trudinger.